# Versión de offsetHeight para Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este código funciona perfectamente en Firefox pero en Chrome me da error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null`. ¿Qué otra propiedad podria usar en vez de el `offsetHeight` que tanto Chrome como Firefox la acepten?

Y otra pregunta. No sé por qué, pero el div `w-arrow-contact` nunca me señala la tardera opción (branding) al hacer scroll. Y he chequeado por consola y cuando estoy en el último y penúltimo punto del scroll y me da TRUE la condicional que desencadena el evento `arrowBrand()`.

```js
 function arrowAbout(){
  document.getElementById("arrow-contact").className = "w-arrow-contact w-about";
 }

 function arrowTerms(){
  document.getElementById("arrow-contact").className = "w-arrow-contact w-terms";
 }

 function arrowBrand(){
  document.getElementById("arrow-contact").className = "w-arrow-contact w-brand";
 }

 var totalHeight = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,  document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
   if(  window.pageYOffset >= document.getElementById("content-about").offsetHeight && window.pageYOffset <= document.getElementById("content-brand").offsetHeight){
     arrowTerms();
   }else if((window.pageYOffset+150) >= document.documentElement.scrollTopMax){
    arrowBrand();
   }else{
    arrowAbout();
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
body{ font-family: century Gothic, Verdana; color:#444;}

.sub-menu{
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #444;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 justify-content: center;
 padding-right: 2rem;
 position: fixed;
}

.sub-menu section{
 position:relative;
 text-align:right;
}

.sub-menu a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.w-arrow-contact{
 border-right:11px solid transparent;
 border-top:7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:7px solid transparent;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 position:absolute;
 right:-2rem;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 top:0;
}

.contenido{
 padding:3.5rem 4rem;
  margin-left:250px;
}

#a-about:hover ~ .w-arrow-contact, .w-about{
  border-right:11px solid #fff;
  top:0.8rem;
 }

 #a-terms:hover ~ .w-arrow-contact, .w-terms{
  border-right:11px solid #fff;
  top:3.3rem;
 }

 #a-branding:hover ~ .w-arrow-contact, .w-brand{
  border-right:11px solid #fff;
  top:5.8rem;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="sub-menu  menu-contact">
  <section id="nav-contact">
   <a href="#about" id="a-about" class="smoothScroll" onclick="arrowAbout()">
    Sobre nosotros
   </a>
   <a href="#terms" id="a-terms" class="smoothScroll" onclick="arrowTerms()">
    Términos y condiciones
    </a>
   <a href="#branding" id="a-branding" class="smoothScroll" onclick="arrowBrand()">
    Branding
   </a>
   <div class="w-arrow-contact  w-about" id="arrow-contact"></div>
 </section>
</div>

<section class="contenido  contenido-contact">
 <div id="content-brand">
  <div id="content-terms">
   <div id="content-about">
    <h2 id="about">Sobre nosotros</h2>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et lorem fermentum, lacinia nulla et, posuere lectus. Phasellus gravida maximus tortor malesuada viverra. Etiam euismod ante sit amet ligula lacinia, at facilisis sapien pellentesque. Donec condimentum ligula vitae velit luctus luctus. In id felis dapibus, finibus metus a, aliquet nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean nisl ante, consectetur quis nisi vel, feugiat egestas arcu. In non finibus mi. Nullam vitae rutrum enim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

    Nam ligula erat, aliquam et odio nec, ullamcorper blandit sapien. Proin ornare vel lacus ut finibus. Sed at nibh tortor. Pellentesque at varius erat, id pretium nisl. Quisque sed enim aliquam, rutrum turpis eget, rutrum nibh. Vivamus porta egestas quam ac elementum. Aliquam est magna, ornare at congue at, egestas eu dui. Morbi quis rutrum erat. Praesent finibus nec lectus sed ultrices.

    In vel ultrices felis. Ut nec ultrices magna. Maecenas cursus vel sem nec mattis. Duis fermentum cursus pretium. Curabitur laoreet dolor non porta dignissim. Aliquam ornare in eros eu tempus. Sed laoreet risus purus, quis scelerisque ligula bibendum sit amet. Fusce quis libero vel felis mollis eleifend in varius magna. Fusce porta hendrerit neque, ut eleifend augue ullamcorper lobortis. Proin massa massa, semper sit amet sapien ut, laoreet euismod diam. Proin vitae egestas tellus. 
   </div>
   
   <h2 id="terms">Términos y condiciones</h2>

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et lorem fermentum, lacinia nulla et, posuere lectus. Phasellus gravida maximus tortor malesuada viverra. Etiam euismod ante sit amet ligula lacinia, at facilisis sapien pellentesque. Donec condimentum ligula vitae velit luctus luctus. In id felis dapibus, finibus metus a, aliquet nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean nisl ante, consectetur quis nisi vel, feugiat egestas arcu. In non finibus mi. Nullam vitae rutrum enim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

   Nam ligula erat, aliquam et odio nec, ullamcorper blandit sapien. Proin ornare vel lacus ut finibus. Sed at nibh tortor. Pellentesque at varius erat, id pretium nisl. Quisque sed enim aliquam, rutrum turpis eget, rutrum nibh. Vivamus porta egestas quam ac elementum. Aliquam est magna, ornare at congue at, egestas eu dui. Morbi quis rutrum erat. Praesent finibus nec lectus sed ultrices.

   In vel ultrices felis. Ut nec ultrices magna. Maecenas cursus vel sem nec mattis. Duis fermentum cursus pretium. Curabitur laoreet dolor non porta dignissim. Aliquam ornare in eros eu tempus. Sed laoreet risus purus, quis scelerisque ligula bibendum sit amet. Fusce quis libero vel felis mollis eleifend in varius magna. Fusce porta hendrerit neque, ut eleifend augue ullamcorper lobortis. Proin massa massa, semper sit amet sapien ut, laoreet euismod diam. Proin vitae egestas tellus. 

   </div>
  
  <h2 id="branding">Branding</h2>
   
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et lorem fermentum, lacinia nulla et, posuere lectus. Phasellus gravida maximus tortor malesuada viverra. Etiam euismod ante sit amet ligula lacinia, at facilisis sapien pellentesque. Donec condimentum ligula vitae velit luctus luctus. In id felis dapibus, finibus metus a, aliquet nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean nisl ante, consectetur quis nisi vel, feugiat egestas arcu. In non finibus mi. Nullam vitae rutrum enim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

  Nam ligula erat, aliquam et odio nec, ullamcorper blandit sapien. Proin ornare vel lacus ut finibus. Sed at nibh tortor. Pellentesque at varius erat, id pretium nisl. Quisque sed enim aliquam, rutrum turpis eget, rutrum nibh. Vivamus porta egestas quam ac elementum. Aliquam est magna, ornare at congue at, egestas eu dui. Morbi quis rutrum erat. Praesent finibus nec lectus sed ultrices.

  In vel ultrices felis. Ut nec ultrices magna. Maecenas cursus vel sem nec mattis. Duis fermentum cursus pretium. Curabitur laoreet dolor non porta dignissim. Aliquam ornare in eros eu tempus. Sed laoreet risus purus, quis scelerisque ligula bibendum sit amet. Fusce quis libero vel felis mollis eleifend in varius magna. Fusce porta hendrerit neque, ut eleifend augue ullamcorper lobortis. Proin massa massa, semper sit amet sapien ut, laoreet euismod diam. Proin vitae egestas tellus. 

 </div>
</section> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con la propiedad `offsetHeight` sino con el objeto sobre el que la llamas que es nulo.

Comment: Pero si yo tengo en el documento yo tengo `#content-about` `#content-terms` y `#content-brand`. ¿Cómo van a ser nulos? 
Chrome ya no acepta el offsetHeight https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2889

Comment: El mensaje de error es clarisimo `Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null` eso significa que estas llamando a la propiedad `offsetHeight` de algo nulo

Comment: Creo que viene porque en `document.body.offsetHeight` estas llamando a `document.body`antes de que se haya cargado todo y por lo tanto vale nulo. Tendrias que meterlo dentro del `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...}`

Comment: Ya funciona para Chrome. Fue un error mío. Lo que sigo sin entender es por qué jamás me señala cuando estoy en el último div `#content-brand`. Solo apunta ahí cuando le doy click, al `a href` respectivo

Comment: Basicamente es porque no se cumple nunca la condicion `if((window.pageYOffset+150) >= document.documentElement.scrollTopMax)`

Comment: Desde la consola, en los dos últimos movimientos del scroll, me aparece que esa condición me da `true`

Answer (score 1):

Para que funcione el javascript hay que cambiar el orden de las condicionales, porque nunca "entraba" en el segundo `else if` ya que el primer `if` daba `true`.

```
document.getElementById("arrow").className += " active-info";

function arrowAbout(){
    document.getElementById("arrow-contact").className = "w-arrow-contact w-about";
}

function arrowTerms(){
    document.getElementById("arrow-contact").className = "w-arrow-contact w-terms";
}

function arrowBrand(){
    document.getElementById("arrow-contact").className = "w-arrow-contact w-brand";
}

var totalHeight = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,  document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        if( (window.pageYOffset) == document.documentElement.scrollTopMax ){
            arrowBrand();
        }else if(  window.pageYOffset >= document.getElementById("content-about").offsetHeight && window.pageYOffset <= document.getElementById("content-brand").offsetHeight){
                arrowTerms();
        }else{
            arrowAbout();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola @MarisabelGC si esta es la respuesta correcta no olvides marcarla como tal, saludos.